# How do I use winforms with abstract class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, abstract-class, factory

I have an abstract class "Element" which its instances have to use the function DrawRectangle() from System.Drawing.
The problem is that because the class is abstract it can't inherit from FORM so the program doesn't recognize the classes..
How can I solve this?
I've tried puting a variable of type Form inside Element and didn't work.
I also tried the opposite, puting an Element variable inside Form.
It is my first time with Winform and C#...
It is supposed to be a mouse race game, the objects drawn in page are supposed to chase the mouse or go in other directions but I need it to be object oriented.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyMouseGame
{
    public abstract class Element
    {
        //Form1 myForm = new Form1();// not sure I need it
        public enum EnumShape { Square, Circle, Triangle }
        public enum EnumType { Chase, Escape, Random }

        //variables
        private double X { get; set; }
        private double Y { get; set; }
        private int Size { get; }
        private int Speed { get; }
        private EnumShape Shape { get; set; }
        protected EnumType Type { get; set; }

        private static Random R = new Random();

        //methods

        public int generateRandomNum()
        {
            int randomNum = R.Next(20, 100);
            return randomNum;
        }

        public Element()
        {
            X= 0;
            Y = 0;
            Shape = 0;
            Size = generateRandomNum();
            Speed = generateRandomNum();
            Type = 0;
        }

        public void ElementsFactory()
        {

        }

        public void hitTarget(e) { }
        public abstract void Draw(Form1 g); //here I tried to pass a form inside 
        public abstract void Move();
    }
}
```

```
//example of one of the instances classes of element
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;


namespace MyMouseGame
{
    class E_Escape : Element
    {
        int move_circleX = 0;
        int move_circleY = 0;

        bool flag = false;

        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(10, 70, 35, 35);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

        //circle
        public E_Escape()
        {
        }
        public override void Draw(Form1 g) {
            g.DrawEllipse(p, circle);
            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), circle);
        }

        public override void Move() {
            if (!flag)
            {
                if (circle.X >= panel1.Width - 2)
                    flag = true;
                circle.X += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                if (circle.X <= 30)
                    flag = false;
                circle.X -= 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;


namespace MyMouseGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        Element [] elements= new Element[3];

        public Form1()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
    
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            //timer set
            t.Interval = 100;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            t.Start();

        }

        private void recThreadTracker()
        {
            //move rectangle
            while (true)//here I tried to call element finction draw
            {
                elements[0].Draw(g);
                elements[1].Draw(g);
                elements[2].Draw(g);
            }
        }

        public void threadCounter()
        {
            long counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                counter++;
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    lcountRes.Text = counter.ToString();
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
           

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread counterThread = new Thread(threadCounter);
            counterThread.Start();
            Thread recTrackThread = new Thread(recThreadTracker);
            recTrackThread.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Element elements in elements)
            {
                elements.Move();
            }

            //Refresh();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Element` doesn't need to be abstract, does it?

Comment: I think it does because it doesnt implement its methods itself but its 'childs' do

Comment: The form class doesn't need to inherit from `Element` - it needs to be passed the concrete instance(s) for it to draw.

Comment: _g = panel1.CreateGraphics();_ A Paint event should use the e.Graphics parameter. Also: Never try to cache a Graphics object if you want persistent graphics. - Also: `t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);` This adds another Tick call upon each Paint call. Surely not what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by Never try to cache a Graphics object? Also: e.CreateGaphics() doesnt recognize the create graphics method. What to do? Also: If I want diferent elements drawn should i do i in different threads?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Because, in the `Paint` event handler (or `OnPaint()` override), the Graphics object you **must** use is `e.Graphics`. That's your Graphics object. Never try to create one and store it to draw on a Control's DC (already mentioned? Well, let's mention it again).

Answer (score 0):

The drawing routine needs two things. A `Graphics`  object, and the `Size` of the drawing area.

For example, to draw a circle on the center of the graphics area

```
public void Draw(Graphics g, Size target)
{
    int diameter = 16;
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, target.Width/2 - diameter/2, target.Height/2 - diameter/2, diameter, diameter);
}
```

And in your form's paint event you call all the draw functions

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var item in Elements)
    {
        item.Draw(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientSize);
    }
}
```